# Is UDP a Transport Layer Protocol in the TCP/IP model?

Tags: udp

In some tables explaining the TCP/IP model, both UDP and TCP are set as examples as protocols for the Transport Layer. Does this mean that UDP is part of the TCP/IP protocol suite?

[image: A table explaining the TCP/IP model]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is part of the suite. See [RFC768](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc768).